# Postman how continue the Runner after the Could not get any response error

Tags: postman

I have a collection in Postman with 4 POST/GET Requests.
After starting this collection, the runner stops at the first request because of the error: Could not get any response error, witout running any other next request.

Not useful to me how can resolve this error, I know  the endpoint is not responding    for a network issue, but simply I would have to log this first result as FAIL in the summary test results (maybe by using some pm.response.to.have.status function?) and continue the running to the next request until the end of the collection

Best Regards
Giancarlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the endpoint is not responding, there is no pm.response.* so you couldn't handle it with pm.reponse. In the other case, if there is an errornous response, the whole collection wouldn't stop (if there is no script error).

That fact, that the PostMan-runner is stopping is quite bad, but unfortunately a known issue:
https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3360

Here is your solution: You can handle this by use of [NewMan](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman), the CLI postman runner.
Newman is continuing the tests-run by default.

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsonData;
try { jsonData = pm.response.json(); } catch(e) {}
```

Try above. I am also using above and it worked well.

**Reference link**

- https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3845#issuecomment-501210716

Comment: Format your answers properly. Also, make sure your answer actually answers the asked quedtion.